# How to combine multiple odds ratio from different time points

Tags: meta-analysis, odds-ratio

I am doing a meta-analysis where my size effect is the odds ratio.
There is a study with multiple odds ratios for different times.
For example: I want the odds ratio for positive UDS for the intake of amphetamines

My end goal is to calculate to combine the odds ratio over various times, to calculate an odds ratio that would most represent the chance of positive UDS for opioids for any previous or actual positive amphetamine positive UDS.

[image: Study report]

Comment: Welcome to CV, Gabriel.  It's unclear what would constitute "solve it."  "Extract a desired odds ratio from the input data"?  "Perform some kind of an unstated meta-analysis on various odds ratios"?  "Combine the odds ratios in some meaningful way over various times"? Something else?

Comment: Thanks for your response! My end goal is to combine the odds ratio over various times, I want to calculate an odds ratio that would most represent the chance of positive UDS for opioids for any previous positive amphetamine positive UDS.

Comment: It's hard to see how one could determine such a thing from such a summary.  Wouldn't you need to follow each subject over time?

Comment: Yes, I would. The study does not give me further information on that. I was looking for a way to at least statically approach that. To combine these odds ratio over various times

Comment: I don't know how to proceed. I might need to choose a single odds ratio for an individual time point, but I don't find a reasonable explanation.
Also, I don't know if it is possible to combine this information somehow.

Comment: If you are looking for the average over all time points then you can pool the odds. If you want to take into account the time factor then this paper might be helpful: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5087886/

Comment: This paper is helpful. The problem is that I don't really know what is the best approach for me. I am performing a meta-analysis and all other studies report a single odds ratio for a unique timeframe. I don't know if would be appropriate to pool the odds ratio for this study only, or to perform a linear model only for the study and then use the resulting odds ratio in the meta-analysis.
Any ideas on what approach would be more reasonable?

Comment: Is it statistically possible, using the table,  to calculate the odds ratio of positive opioid UDS at 12 months for any previous positive amphetamine (at 12, 9, 6, 3 months, and baseline)?

Comment: Select a sound time point (from a clinical/biological point of view), and then for each study, extract the odds ratio closest to that target time point.